# menu callback path construction

Tags: hooks, uri, routes

It seems there is hardly any documentation on page call backs using URLS

This being the case I have 2 questions:

What is a legal callback path?
and what becomes the URL to access that path?

Here is the code on my custom module:

```
  $menu['tipFeed/arguments/%'] = array(
'page callback' => 'tipfeed_create',
'page arguments' => array(2),
'access arguments' => array('access arguments page'),
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Here is the function it refers to:

```
function tipfeed_create($first){
     return 'cool';
}
```

My module is called tipFeed.

why is the URL http://www.example.com/tipFeed/arguments/1 saying page not found?

Any help would be great, thank you

Comment: I've made a couple mistakes when doing hook_menu entries.
Make sure your hook_menu callback is returning $menu. Also as @zhilevan said, clear the cache after any hook_menu change. For this callback, % is a wildcard. tipFeed/arguments will be an invalid path, but tipFeed/arguments/anythinghere would be a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

everything is ok, just try to clear cache and **don't forget never, after any change in hook_menu clear cache**